# How to read word using lex and yacc?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I have written a program to read data of a text file using lex and yacc.I want to compare "State" on that text file and retrieve the word after that.
I have used below code.But it gives all the text in that text file.Please help

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]*"\n" { if (strcmp("State: ",yytext)!=0)
{
printf(yytext,"\n");}
}
```

Comment: Your code prints everything that *isn't* equal to "State: ". Was that your intention? NB you don't need strcmp() if you're already using *lex/flex.*

Comment: I need to print words after "State: "

Comment: My text file is State: Drive State: Park

Answer (score 1):

You'd better define more correctly your token parsing and grammar, so it gets the value you want by building the AST, and then you can deal with your values:

lexer.l:

```
"State" {
    return STATE;
}

[0-9a-zA-Z]* {
    return STATE_VALUE;
}
```

parser.y:

```
%token STATE
%token STATE_VALUE
%left ':'

state_command: STATE ':' STATE_VALUE {
    // do stuff here
}
```

of course it's far from being complete, but it's just to give you the idea. You should really have a read of the dragons book: [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and [Principles of Compiler Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design).

You can also find simple examples that could help you a lot building your compiler: http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/index.html or http://aquamentus.com/tut_lexyacc.html

Comment: I believe that the production should be `state_command: STATE ':' STATE_VALUE`.